# how should I access data input from a GUI to use in my other Java classes, in a way that upholds dependency inversion principle

Tags: java, user-interface

I know how to set up a java GUI (with swing) and use components, actionlisteners etc.  What I am not sure about, is how I should pass informtation input to my gui (in a field, for instance) to classes in my application so that they can process the information.

For instance, I set up a GUI to take a filename in.  I want to pass the filename on to a reader class that I have set up, so that it can read the data in that file and make it available to other classes for processing.  The simplest way I know to do this, is to store the filename in a field within my gui class, and provide a get() method for that field.  Then, in the main() method I use to create the GUI, I can call the get() method and then pass it along to whatever else needs it.  Is this a reasonable approach, or is there some other better way?  I think there may be more advanced ways to launch the GUI, and if so, I am not sure how to use them and still be able to pass the filename along.

Comment: Look up MVC model and how to use it in Swing. The whole interface builds on it. Look down in my answer below to find further details and an example.

Comment: I was hoping to minimize the coupling between the UI controllers and the model.  For instance in your ActionListener your instantiate a Model Class.  As the UI and Model get more complicated, these kind of couplings could be buried in controller methods...no way to make this cleaner?

Comment: That is exactly what your controller is for. The controller makes the connection between your data model and your view. Sometimes if you have a lot of logic you make another layer, called the business-layer. There you got all your logic. And the controller rlly only links ui to data and calls methods from business instead of defining them. This is clean. Somewhere you have to define the mapping between data, functions and the view elements they belong to. To do this all in one controller layer is cleaner than spreading it up

Comment: Additionally working with models like MVC has the big advantage of modularity. You can simply by modifying the Model class in my example change your data input from files to a database without having to change anything of the other layers. If you would put it all together you would have to redo the whole thing. I don't really understand what you want to be "cleaner" or what could get "buried"

Comment: doesn't the suggestion below break the dependency inversion principle?  I guess this is what I am looking to uphold.

Comment: Dont think so. Model and Controller are both lower level layers inheriting ActionListener and DefaultListModel as their higher level layers.
Besides that i dont see how you could split it up more without doing unnecessary work. Swing builds up on the mvc model, so that is what should be used when working with it. Don't use a structure your chosen framework isn't made for. To make it fit the DIP more you should use "ListModel<String>" instead of "Model". But thats pretty much it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a button that the user presses to initiate loading the file, you can attach an action listener to this button. The action listener can read the filename from the input text field and pass the filename to the reader class to load the file (and the file loading preferably happens on a different thread from the GUI thread).

Answer (score 0):

> store the filename in a field within my gui class

You should create another class with getters and setters to store the values from your GUI. Lets call that class ValueFromUI class. The GUI class should only be used for things concerning the GUI.

> Then, in the main() method I use to create the GUI, I can call the get() method and then pass it along to whatever else needs

When it comes to GUI applications, if you do actions on the same thread as that of the GUI, the GUI will freeze. You must have had a button for the user to click right ? So there will be an action listener for that button. In the action listener of that button, you get the value from the textbox and set it to the ValueFromUI class object and then pass that object to whatever file processors you might need. Now this operation should be done on a different thread, else your UI will freeze while this operation runs.

You can learn more about it at this link, especially the part which says 
"2.  The Infamous "Unresponsive User Interface" "
 https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J5e_multithreading.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for sounds like a proper model to structure your project. The easiest an for your example most appropriate model would be the MVC model.

MCV stands for Model View Controll. It describes how the interaction between data layer (model) and ui layer (view) happens through the logic-layer (controll). Swing works with this concept as well. Look it up if you need to know more about it.

Here is an easy example. Picking a file from your pc and loading all of its lines into a list.

Here is your ui (View)

```
public class View extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public View() {
    initUi();
  }

  private void initUi() {
    final JPanel root = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    final JList<String> list = new JList<>();
    final JButton button = new JButton("Choose file");

    final Controller controller = new Controller(list, root);
    button.addActionListener(controller);

    final GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    root.add(button, constraints);
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    root.add(list, constraints);

    add(root);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

}
```

Which accesses your logic-layer (Controller)

```
public class Controller implements ActionListener {

  private final JList<String> list;
  private final JPanel root;
  private final JFileChooser chooser;

  public Controller(final JList<String> list, final JPanel root) {
    this.list = list;
    this.root = root;
    this.chooser = new JFileChooser();
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
    final int returnValue = this.chooser.showOpenDialog(this.root);
    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        final File selectedFile = this.chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            final Model model = new Model(selectedFile);
            this.list.setModel(model);
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // couldn't read file. maybe directory or missing permission
            this.list.setModel(null);
        }

    }
  }

}
```

Which connects your ui-layer with your data-layer (Model)

```
public class Model extends DefaultListModel<String> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public Model(final File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String line = scanner.nextLine();
        addElement(line);
    }
    scanner.close();
  }

}
```

This way your logic-layer (where you perform all your actions) always has access to both, your ui-layer and your model-layer and therefore has all you need to do your stuff. While the model-layer and the ui-layer don't see anything of each other and live in peace happily ever after.

You can run it like this to try it out.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final View view = new View();
    view.setVisible(true);
    view.setSize(300, 500);
}
```